# viewholder onclickListener null object reference

Tags: adapter, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

Attempt to invoke interface method `'void com.example.imovie.adapter.MovieItemClickListener.onMovieClick(com.example.imovie.models.Movie, android.widget.ImageView)'` on a null object reference

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context ;
    List<Movie> mData;
    MovieItemClickListener movieItemClickListener;


    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> mData, MovieItemClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
        movieItemClickListener = listener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_movie,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {


        myViewHolder.TvTitle.setText(mData.get(i).getTitle());
        myViewHolder.ImgMovie.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getThumbnail());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private TextView TvTitle;
        private ImageView ImgMovie;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            TvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_movie_title);
            ImgMovie = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_movie_img);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    movieItemClickListener.onMovieClick(mData.get(getAdapterPosition()),ImgMovie);//i have  a null object reference
                }
            });


        }
    }
}



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements MovieItemClickListener {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private List<Slide> listSlides;
    private ViewPager slidePager;
    private TabLayout indicator;
    private RecyclerView moviesRV;
    private RecyclerView moviesRV2;
    private MovieItemClickListener movieItemClickListener;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        slidePager = root.findViewById(R.id.slider_pager);
        indicator = root.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        moviesRV = root.findViewById(R.id.rsViewMovies);
        moviesRV2 = root.findViewById(R.id.rsViewMovies2);
        iniSlider();

        final SliderPagerAdapter sliderPagerAdapteradapter = new SliderPagerAdapter(getContext(), listSlides);
        final MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getContext(), DateSource.getPopularMovies(), movieItemClickListener);


        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SliderTimer(), 4000, 6000);

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

                slidePager.setAdapter(sliderPagerAdapteradapter);
                indicator.setupWithViewPager(slidePager, true);
                moviesRV.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
                moviesRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

                moviesRV2.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
                moviesRV2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            }
        });

        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMovieClick(Movie movie, ImageView imageView) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MovieDetailActivity.class);


        intent.putExtra("title", movie.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("imgURL", movie.getThumbnail());
        intent.putExtra("imgCover", movie.getCoverPhoto());


        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),
                imageView, "sharedName");

        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());


        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "item clicked : " + movie.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    class SliderTimer extends TimerTask {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (getActivity() != null) {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (slidePager.getCurrentItem() < listSlides.size() - 1) {
                            slidePager.setCurrentItem(slidePager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                        } else {
                            slidePager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }


    private void iniSlider() {

        listSlides = new ArrayList<>();
        listSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.a, "slide title \n movie title"));
        listSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.b, "slide title"));
        listSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.a, "slide title \n movie title"));
        listSlides.add(new Slide(R.drawable.b, "slide title"));

    }


}
```

Comment: 1) You'd better to paste the Exception stacktrace, which contains source filenames and line numbers, instead of just Exception message. Though for this question the message is enough. 
2) better formatting is welcome.

Comment: Formatting improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, `HomeFragment.movieItemClickListener` is never initialized.

You may want to make the following changes in `HomeFragment`:

1. Delete the line

```
private MovieItemClickListener movieItemClickListener;
```

2. In this line

```
final MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getContext(), DateSource.getPopularMovies(), movieItemClickListener);
```

change `movieItemClickListener` to `this`, because `HomeFragment` implements `MovieItemClickListener`.

That should fix the NullPointerException.